# Reading information in a .get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

If you were to run this code in `Console` on the page, you would get the value of the element-

```
$('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value
```

But i'm having trouble running this in a get request (So I dont have to visit the page to get the value of that element). This is what i have so far (Which doesnt work):

```
$.get(
    link,
    function (data){
        console.log($('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could parse the ajax return-`data` and wrap them into a jQuery-Object so you can go through `.find()` to get the elements-value:

```
$.get(
    link,
    function (data){
        console.log($(data).find('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    }
);
```

The returned data must be HTML and an form field with the name `__RequestVerificationToken` must exist.

To check if it was successful you can use something like this:

```
$.get(link,function(data) {
    var $tokenObj = $(data).find('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]'));
    if($tokenObj.length > 0) {
        console.log("the token is: "+$tokenObj.val());
    } else {
        console.log("Ooops, no token found.");
    }
});
```